# Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle; Could an electron from one of my skins atoms randomly appear on Jupiter?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Is there an infinitely small probability that a particle on earth could "randomly" appear on Jupiter or elsewhere (since the probability of its position approaches 0, but never reaches it)?

After all, HUP is a real problem/ limitation to the max speed of our processors, because at some point transistors will become so small, that the electrons will "spontaneously" cross over the semiconductors switches.

Or are those 2 examples (electrons crossing over an extremely tiny semiconductor barrier vs electrons randomly popping up on Jupiter) completely uncomparable? If so, I'd love to understand why.

**Disclaimer**: I'm an idiot with very limited knowledge about all this (well, at least compared to a real physicist).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an infinitely small probability that an electron could go to any point in the universe.  All of the probabilities add up to 100%.  There's obviously a 99.9999....% chance that your electrons stay in your body.

Here's a good resource on HUP:

https://www.theguardian.com/science/2013/nov/10/what-is-heisenbergs-uncertainty-principle

Comment: I don't think that this is true. The electron should not disappear and appear somewhere else. It says only how precise we can measure the position and momentum at the same time.

Comment: But it was proven that electrons can be in more than one place at the same time during the sheet experiment.  This means there's a probability that an electron could be anywhere in the universe.

Comment: You mixed up two things. The first "the probability to find a electron is non-zero everywhere if this electron is nonlocalized" and the second that there is an inaccuracy to measure the position and the momentum at the same time.